# 1988 Prelude guages stop working when hot

Tags: electrical

My tach,temp guage and fuel guage work fine when car is cool but when the car gets hot ( just sitting parked motor not running ) all 3 guages quit working . Any ideas ? Would deeply appreciate any ideas on what is causing it .

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar on a GM product in the early 80's. It was a cold solder joint on the voltage regulator feeding the guages in the instrument cluster. You can also check for cracks or breaks in the circuit board. This involves removing the instrument cluster and carefully examine visually. Check for continuity using an multimeter.